# MSMQ Trigger is not firing to execute console app in windows 8

Tags: message-queue, msmq

I have a console app that just writes to log file when it executes (as a test)
Eventually it will use the data sent by message from MSMQ for processing.
Current when I send the message to the queue, I see them.
But they always stay there.

Both Message Queue and Message Trigger Service running in windows
Console app is an exe with main method like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _log.Debug("# of Args: " + args.Length);
                foreach (string str in args)
                {
                    _log.Debug("arg=" + str);
                }
}
```

**I am sending MessageBody, Id etc as parameter to the console app**

**What am I doing wrong that causing the trigger not to fire on my queue?**

Trigger info:

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: This is working on windows 7 machine. Have to troubleshoot on win 8!

Comment: One trick I try is to set the trigger to launch notepad. If I can't see a Notepad window then I use Task Manager to see if there is a Notepad.exe process. That's to check if the process has been launched in a different context that doesn't interact with the desktop. Obviously troubleshooting is different depending on whether notepad is there or not.